# Comparing between strings goes wrong

Tags: java, android

I have a class that generates the phone location and it updates a TextView every time a new location has retrieved.
We will name this class as Track.

The Track class contains a sendLocation object which is a Thread.
The sendLocation contatins a Track object and it checks every x time if the TextView has changed(the Track class got a method that returns the TextView string), how?

It save the last address in a string and compares between the last address and the Text View address every x time, if they are diffrent it sends this string to my db.
I do that to avoid duplicates.

My question is, how come it keeps sending same addresses to my db?I mean comparing strings is pretty simple.
Here is some code:

```
if(!t1.getAddress().equals(lastAddress))
{
    lastAddress = t1.getAddress();
    //send last address to the db
    //sleep for a while
}
```

t1 is a Track instance.

And here is the getAddress method in Track:

```
public String getAddress()
{
    return this.mAddress.getText().toString();
}
```

What's is wrong?it's a simple string comparing!!

Comment: I suggest you add some logging to see what `getAddress()` and `lastAddress` are in each case...

Comment: Try logging both the values. Check the valies it may be some extra whitespace in the end/start, I can't see anything else...

Comment: I suspect your problem is in code that you're not showing.  Can you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

Comment: Are use sure the addresses are equal? maybe different related to spaces? I would log both addresses to compare it by hand for testing (or use a debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having a [race codition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). The variable that saves `lastAddress` is still not updated with the latest value when you're comparing.

In a multithread program different threads saves copies of the same shared variable for efficiency. This copy will be updated from time to time, but does not guarantee that all of your threads will see the same value every time they access it. For that, you have to use `synchronized` in the blocks where you update/read the variable, or set it to be `volatile`, making all threads points to the same value of variable instead of having a copy of its own.

---

**EDIT:**

A good link to understand more about what may be happening to you: [Threading Stories: Volatile and Synchronized](http://java.dzone.com/articles/threading-stories-volatile-and?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20javalobby/frontpage%20%28Javalobby%20/%20Java%20Zone%29)

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions

- Using `UNIQUE` on column in your DB (so it won't contain duplicated data)
- Debugging the code line `...equals(...`, and find out if the strings aren't really different

Comment: I'd suggest both simultaneously :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how much this applies to Andriod development but in regular Java world when you have a problem like this it means your thread has a local copy of the variable and that's when you start defining members as volatile. In your case I am not convinced the reference to track object gets updated but you can try and see if defining that reference as volatile will do any help.

Answer (score 0):

After **lastAddress = t1.getAddress();** if lastAddress is the same value,

you have a problem with this line,

**!t1.getAddress().equals(lastAddress))**  so you should debug this line

watch

lastAddress

t1.getAddress()